# shortest path to all points of mesh

Tags: c++, boost, cgal

I am working on watertight meshes and what I am trying is to get the shortest path on the surface of the mesh from every vertex in the mesh to every other vertex in the mesh.

E.g. when there are 100 vertices in the mesh i would get 100X100 distances and I want to store those in an 100x100 distance Matrix.

I use CGAL (and therefore also BOOST) and I have nearly no experience in both of them.

This is what i have so far:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Random.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_items_with_id_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_shortest_path.h>
#include <CGAL/boost/graph/graph_traits_Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/boost/graph/iterator.h>
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel, CGAL::Polyhedron_items_with_id_3> Polyhedron_3;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh_shortest_path_traits<Kernel, Polyhedron_3> Traits;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh_shortest_path<Traits> Surface_mesh_shortest_path;
typedef Surface_mesh_shortest_path::Shortest_path_result Shortest_path_result;

typedef boost::graph_traits<Polyhedron_3> Graph_traits;
typedef Graph_traits::vertex_iterator vertex_iterator;
typedef Graph_traits::vertex_descriptor vertex_desc;
typedef Graph_traits::face_iterator face_iterator;

typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> distArray;
typedef distArray::index distArrayIndex;

class DistanceMeasure {
public:
    static distArray getDistances(Polyhedron_3 p);
};
```

as my header file and:

```
#include "DistanceMeasure.h"

distArray DistanceMeasure::getDistances(Polyhedron_3 p) {
    distArray dists(boost::extents[p.size_of_vertices()][p.size_of_vertices()]);
    // pick up a random face
    CGAL::set_halfedgeds_items_id(p);

    vertex_iterator pit = vertices(p).first;

    // construct a shortest path query object and add a source point
    Surface_mesh_shortest_path shortest_paths(p);

    //add all points from p to the source points
    for ( pit = vertices(p).first; pit != vertices(p).end(); pit++)
        shortest_paths.add_source_point(*pit);

    //for all points in p get distance to all the other points
    vertex_iterator vit, vit_end;
    for ( boost::tie(vit, vit_end) = vertices(p);
    vit != vit_end; ++vit)
    {
        //get distances
        Shortest_path_result res = shortest_paths.shortest_distance_to_source_points(*vit);

        //iterate over all query results
        Surface_mesh_shortest_path::Source_point_iterator spit;
        int count = 0;
        for(spit = res.second; spit != shortest_paths.source_points_end(); spit++) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return dists;
}
```

for my source file.

In my unterstanding i woult get the distances to all the other points in res and can iterate over them in

```
for(spit = res.second; spit != shortest_paths.source_points_end(); spit++) {
            count++;
}
```

Therefore i got 2 questions:
First:
Am I getting this right? Do i have all the distances in res?
And second:
How do I get the id's of the vertices and distances to them in my result (and also from spit) to be able to identify them and store their distance in the dists array.

What I thought so far is, that maybe the order is in the order I put the points into the source points.

When I run it with e.g. 100 vertices and use count to count the number of vertices in res I woult get.

100
99
98
97
96
95
..
2
1

I thought that this might be because CGAL does not compute a distance twice.
Still I am not sure about the indexes.

Thank you for your Answers
Steffen

Comment: What type of mesh are we talking about here?  If we are talking about a mappable TIN (triangulated terrain model) you can get a surface distance by cutting a section through the TIN and computing 3d distances between edges of triangles cut.  This is not necessarily the shortest distance, e.g. going around a steep hill might cover less distance than going over it.  If it is a non-mappable TIN (e.g. a triangulation of a complex pipe network) finding any path between any two vertices is not trivial and find the shortest path potentially very complex.

Comment: Given your references to polyhedra, I'm guessing the surface is the outer surface of a polyhedral mesh, which again becomes complex is that mesh is not convex.  For this type of stuff, Joe O'Rourke's Computational Geometry in C is worth a read, as is Edelsbrunner's Geometry and Topology for mesh generation.

Comment: I'm using mashes from .off files. so basically all I got is the mashes surface and I need the geodesic distance of the vertices.

Comment: thank you verry much for your answer (I have been driving with my car when i read it...) now after thinking about your answer I think my idea was wrong... I actually don't want is the shortest path! What I want the path between the edgecuts! Do you know if this is easily possible with CGAL or would you recommend coding it by my self?

Comment: Ok, it looks like your problem already has a documented solution with sample source on the CGAL page here; http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_shortest_path/index.html

Comment: that's where I got my code from but i did not know how to get the distances to all source point and not obly the first. I am kind of confused with the iterator...

Comment: For edge cuts, we're talking about a cutting plane (vertical for a map).  I'd do this by triangulating the polygons in the .off, intersecting each triangle with the cutting plane, and where an intersection exists, add its planar length to the total to form your 3d travelled distance between points.

Comment: Never used GDAL, so not sure I can help much beyond this.

Comment: well you helped verry mouch with your other comments thank you!! I will give it a try!

Answer (score -1):

For everybody with a similar Problem:
I can't give a solution for the first Problem I stated but the Intersection Problem might be computed in CGAL with something like this:
http://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/index.html